# If phosphorus doesnt have a free electron then after doping silico, how is there a free electron that can move?

Tags: electrons, atoms

Phosphorus while bonding with silicon offers 5 electron so 4 of them bond leaving 1 extra electron, my question is how does that electron break out of its valence band? There should just be 1 extra electron left in the shell that cant move after bonding how can it move to the p type silicon,  phosphorus isn't a conductor, it doesnt have free electrons that can move and break through.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is that when P is part of the Si lattice, the low energy valence states are all occupied by electrons. Via the Pauli Exclusion Principle, this forces the spare electron into a state whose binding energy is only ~0.045 eV. That's so low that those electrons are easily excited thermally into the conduction band.